# Understanding a notion of family of Jacobians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am currently studying A. Beauville's article [*Determinantal Hypersurfaces*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1030132707).

At (3.2), the author discuss about a family of Jacobians:

> For $\delta\in\mathbf{Z}$, let $\mathcal{J}_d^\delta\rightarrow |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d) |_{sm}$ be
>   the family of degree-$\delta$
>   Jacobians:
>   $\mathcal{J}_d^\delta$
>   parameterizes pairs
>   $(C,L)$
>   of a smooth plane
>   curve of degree
>   $d$
>   and a line bundle of degree
>   $\delta$
>   on $C$.
>   Finally, we denote by
>   $\Theta_d$
>   the divisor in
>   $\mathcal{J}_d^\delta$
>   consisting of pairs
>   $(C,L)$ with $H^0(C,L)\neq 0$.
>   It is an ample
>   divisor, so its complement in
>   $\mathcal{J}_d^\delta$
>   is affine.

I do not understand what exactly is this family of Jacobians. How does the space $\mathcal{J}_d^\delta$ look like and the map onto $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d) |_{sm}$? Why is that divisor ample?

I only know that a Jacobian variety of a curve $C$ is a torus which can be identified with the space $\textrm{Pic}^0(C)$ of degree-$0$ line bundles.

I would be very grateful if you could explain me this definition or if you would give valuable references.